# IIS URl Rewrite/Redirect - Why is a second question mark being added into into my redirect url?

Tags: regex, string, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to redirect to a URL that has more than one parameter. When the page is redirected to the new URL it is failing because a question mark is being added into the query string of my url that should not be there.

The original URL matches on Search/SearchPage.aspx?search=(.*)

The end part is just a number. I then use that number in my redirect URL which looks like this:

```
Login.aspx?query=true&doctypegroupid=105&KT158_0_0_0={R:1}
```

({R:1} is the number from the original URL ex 29987). I don't append the query string and Redirect is permanent.

When I click the original URL it redirects but it gives me a page error. I have determined that it is because the redirect URL is adding an extra question mark like this:

```
Login.aspx?query=true&doctypegroupid=?105&KT158_0_0_0=29987
```

I can not figure out why this extra question mark is being added into the URL. This is happening in multiple browsers. Is there something wrong with the way I am doing this? How can I prevent or at the very least ignore this extra question mark?

The question mark gets added even if I hardcode the URL. So If I set the below as the redirect URL and I click the original URL I would get redirected to the below link but with an extra question mark after the second equal sign.

Login.aspx?query=true&doctypegroupid=105&KT158_0_0_0=6278

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had to change the URL I was matching to from Search/SearchPage.aspx?search=(.*)  to SearchPage.aspx(.*).